# Sorting DataGridView Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

```
    var type = typeof(T);
                var property = type.GetProperty(columnSelectName);
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
                var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
                var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

                if (dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection != SortOrder.Ascending)
                {
                    MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, data.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));

                    bindingSource.DataSource = data.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);

                    dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
                }


public partial class Logs
{
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.id_user.HasValue)
                return this.Users.login;
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public string TypeName
    {
        get
        {
            TypeLogs typeLogs = (TypeLogs)this.type;

            switch (typeLogs)
            {
                case TypeLogs.LogOn:
                    return "Logowanie";
                case TypeLogs.LogOff:
                    return "Wylogowanie";
                case TypeLogs.LogOnFailed:
                    return "Nieudane logowanie";
                case TypeLogs.LogsDelete:
                    return "Usunięto logi";
                default:
                    return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

The specified type member 'Member' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

The specified type member 'Member' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: Are you missing some code here? I don't see the member 'Member' anywhere.  What line is it pointing to?

Comment: Member is TypeName and UserName error to bindingSource.DataSource = data.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);